# How do I mount a SMB share in nautilus?

Tags: nautilus, samba

I have an SMB share through unraid that requires a username and password. On OSX when I click on this share I am prompted to enter a username and password, when I enter this I am connected. When I click on this share in ubuntu I get the message:

"Unable to access location
Failed to retrieve share list from server: Connection refused"

I doesn't even ask me for my username or password. Right clicking the share doesn't give any option to connect as.

Can nautilus not mount shares that require credentials?

Comment: It can mount such shares, but I've seen errors like that when trying to browse the network. Try going to the server directly  by hitting ctrl-l (ell) in Nautilus to get an address box and type in smb://[server-ip-address] or smb://[server-name] (do not actually type the brackets) If it works, you can bookmark it.